# Disk space has different filesystem

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I bought a server that was supposed to have 1 TB of disk space, but after logging in I was faced with the following system files. How can I attach all the space to `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv`?

Results of `df -h` and `lsblk` :

[image]

Comment: I think there is empty space after sda3. Please [edit] your question and add the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`. No screenshots please; copy and paste the text output from your terminal.

Comment: "I bought a server "  1st thing you always do when you get a server from  3rd party is to format the system so that would solve your problem ;-)